# DOMNodeInserted is posible to mark added elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mutation-events

I'm using `DOMNodeInserted` MutationEvent, is any way to select only new inserted elements by using this event?
I have to add class to all inputs when they are inserted to document.
I'm inserting new inputs to form via AJAX request but I can't add it there because this part have to work independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the inserted element with `ev.target` and check with jQuery's `is()` method the tag name.

E.g.:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(ev){
    var _self = $(ev.target);

    if(_self.is('input')) {
        _self.addClass('inputClass');
    } 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KkX3y/1/)